# Proving $f_n(x)=x^2/n$ does NOT converge uniformly to 0 for $n\rightarrow\infty$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

As the title states I'd like to show that $f_n(x)=x^2/n$ does NOT converge uniformly to 0 for $n\rightarrow\infty$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Now taking the negation of uniform convergence I have that there must exist an $\epsilon>0$ such that for any natural number $N$ there exists an x such that if $n\geq N$ then we must have:

$\vert x^2/n\vert\geq\epsilon$.

I'm a little unsure if I've done the negation correctly, but it looks correct to me. However I'm having issues proving the inequality I find after the negation, any advice here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to specify a set in your question.  For example:  Show that $f_n(x)$ does not converge uniformly on $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: @GEdgar thanks! I've fixed it now, it was supposed to be over all $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 1):

That's not quite right. Instead of "if $n\ge N$" you want "there exists $n\ge N$".

In your example, it makes no difference (because the sequence $f_n(x)$ is monotonic for every $x$). But in general it does matter.

So now take, for instance, $\varepsilon=1$. Can you show that for all positive integers $N$, there exists $n\ge N$ and $x\in\Bbb R$ such that $|x^2/n|\ge 1$? (Hint: you can take $n=N$ here.)

Comment: What's the reasoning behind being able to choose $n=N$ since surely $n\geq N$ implies $x^2/n\leq x^2 /N $

Comment: Ahhh, I think I see it now. we say that there must exist $n\geq N$ so we may simply choose $n=N$ and then it is easily solvable by setting for example $x=\sqrt{N+1}$. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: @EmilLenler: Exactly!

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively, it can be helpful to think of $\delta$-$\epsilon$ definitions and their variants involving "$\to \pm\infty$" as a game.

For some specific sequence of functions $\{f_n\}$ and limit function $f$, Alice claims $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly to $f$ on the domain. Bob claims the sequence does not converge uniformly.

In symbols, Alice's claim of uniform convergence is:

$$ \forall \epsilon>0 : \exists N\in \mathbb{N} : \forall n>N : \forall x : |f_n(x)-f(x)| < \epsilon $$

Or in words, "No matter how small $\epsilon$ is, there's an $N$ so that for any $n \geq N$ and everywhere in the domain, the absolute difference between $f_n$ and $f$ is smaller than $\epsilon$.

So to settle the disagreement, they'll play this game:

1. Since Alice claims a result is true for every positive $\epsilon$, the challenge is to Bob, to name a number $\epsilon$ where it's not true. Bob starts by naming a positive number $\epsilon$.
2. Alice names a natural number $N$ she believes is big enough given that $\epsilon$.
3. Bob names an integer $n \geq N$ and a real number $x$.
4. They work out the math. If $|f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$, Alice wins. If $|f_n(x) - f(x)| \geq \epsilon$, Bob wins.

If the function really is uniformly convergent, then there's a way Alice can play to always win. If the function is not uniformly convergent, then there's a way Bob can play to always win.

If Bob can always win, what does that mean? He can choose some number $\epsilon>0$, so that no matter what $N$ Alice picks, Bob can choose $n>N$ and $x$ in the domain so that $|f_n(x)-f(x) \geq \epsilon$. In symbols:

$$ \exists \epsilon>0 : \forall N \in \mathbb{N} : \exists n>N : \exists x : |f_n(x)-f(x)| \geq \epsilon $$

Of course, that's exactly the same as following the negation rules for $\forall$ and $\exists$ on the original symbolic sentence above for uniform convergence.

So for this example with $f_n(x) = x^2/n$ and $f(x)=0$, proving the sequence does not converge uniformly is like finding a winning strategy for Bob. So first name a specific $\epsilon$: $\epsilon = 1$ will work. Alice will name some natural number $N$. What can Bob choose for $n$ and $x$, in terms of $N$, so that $n \geq N$ and $|x^2/n| \geq \epsilon = 1$? One obvious answer is $n=N$, $x=\sqrt{N}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_n = n$, then $f_n(a_n) = n^2/n = n\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow \infty$, and hence $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}|f_n(x)-f(x)|$ does not coverge to zero and so the sequence fails to converge uniformly.